# Async/Await in loop behaviour

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Say I had a list of algorithms, each containing an async call somewhere in the body of that algorithm. The order in which I execute the algorithms is the order in which I want to receive the results. That is, I want the AlgorithmResult List to look like {Algorithm1Result, Algorithm2Result, Algorithm3Result} after all the algorithms have executed. Would I be right in saying that if Algorithm1 and 3 finished before 2 that my results would actually be in the order {Algorithm1Result, Algorithm3Result, Algorithm2Result}

```
var algorithms = new List<Algorithm>(){Algorithm1, Algorithm2, Algorithm3};
var algorithmResults = new List<AlgorithmResults>();

  foreach (var algorithm in algorithms)
  {
     algorithmResults.Add(await algorithm.Execute());
  }
```

Comment: Yes, they will be in order. Also, a tip would be to rename Execute to ExecuteAsync

Comment: This will be executed in the order they are in in algorithms list. Async just waits for the operation to finish

Comment: You are awaiting each execution, therefore executions are executed sequential, not parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, Result would be in the same order you added it to the list, since each operation is being waited for separately.

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task<int> GetResult(int timing)
    {
        return await Task<int>.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(timing * 1000);
            return timing;
        });
    }

    public static async Task<List<int>> GetAll()
    {
        List<int> tasks = new List<int>();

        tasks.Add(await GetResult(3));
        tasks.Add(await GetResult(2));
        tasks.Add(await GetResult(1));

        return tasks;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = GetAll().Result;
    }
}
```

`res` anyway contains list in order it was added, also this is not parallel execution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't add the tasks, but the results of the task after awaiting, they will be in the order you want.

Even if you did not await the result before adding the next task you could get the order you want:

in small steps, showing type awareness:

```
List<Task<AlgorithmResult>> tasks = new List<Task<AlgorithmResult>>();
foreach (Algorithm algorithm in algorithms)
{
    Task<AlgorithmResult> task = algorithm.Execute();

    // don't wait until task Completes, just remember the Task
    // and continue executing the next Algorithm
    tasks.Add(task);
}
```

Now some Tasks may be running, some may already have completed. Let's wait until they are all complete, and fetch the results:

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
List<AlgrithmResults> results = tasks.Select(task => task.Result).ToList();
```